# Using find_last_of with string-C++

Tags: c++, string

I want to extract the last part of a given string. Below is the code snippet:

```
int main ()
{
   const std::string path="C:\Users\rd_nsl_Bentley_1.2.sc";
   auto const pos=path.find_last_of('\\');
   cout<<"pos="<<pos<<endl;
   const auto leaf=path.substr(pos+1);

   std::cout << leaf << '\n';
}
```

My output should be

leaf **rd_nsl_Bentley_1.2.sc**

But the output is

```
pos=18446744073709551615
C:Usersrd_nsl_Bentley_1.2.sc
```

The pos value is arbitary and only "\" is removed from the whole string.

Comment: You didn't escape backslashes in the path string

Comment: Use Filesysystem's `path`

Comment: @JonathanMee: note that [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) is not available until C++17. In earlier C++ versions, you could use [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) instead.

Comment: Aside from the backslash issue, don't forget to check whether the search succeeded before you use the value of `pos`. In this case the search failed, so `pos` should have the value `std::string::npos`, which is an unsigned type with the value -1. Adding 1 to it gives you 0, so `path.substr(pos+1)` should return the entire string.

Comment: @RemyLebeau However `filesystem` been available in gcc, clang, and Visual Studio for several years now, in `experimental` or it's own namespace or whatever. There's no need to use Boost.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `\` characters in your string literal, just like you do for the character literal you are passing to `find_last_of()`.

Change your string literal from this:

```
"C:\Users\rd_nsl_Bentley_1.2.sc"
```

To this:

```
"C:\\Users\\rd_nsl_Bentley_1.2.sc"
```

Or this, if you are using C++11 or later:

```
R"(C:\Users\rd_nsl_Bentley_1.2.sc)"
```

If you don't escape, the compiler will interpret `\U` and `\r` as [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) (where `\U` is invalid as it is not in `\Unnnnnnnn` format, and `\r` is a carriage return).  They will not be interpreted as individual characters `'\'`, `'U'`, `'\'`, `'r'` like you are expecting.

Thus, your string will not have any `'\'` characters for `find_last_of()` to find, so it will return [`std::string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos), which is -1 (aka `18446744073709551615` when interpreted as an unsigned 64-bit number) so `pos+1` would be 0, causing `substr()` to return the original string as-is, and `std::cout` would ignore the `\U` and `\r` escape sequences, producing the output you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your `path` variable, you aren't escaping the `\` characters to properly add them to the string. It's treating the string like you've tried `\U` and `\r` as escaped characters.

Change to `"C:\\Users\\rd_nsl_Bentley_1.2.sc"`

Comment: Or raw string: `R"(C:\Users\rd_nsl_Bentley_1.2.sc)"`